# React Router v4 programmatic redirect: Warning when redirecting to the "same route"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a React app that has a basic structure like seen below. I am attempting to programmatically redirect the user to `/profile` route but I am seeing `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/profile"`.

Inside the `Main` component `header` I have a form that should redirect the user to `/profile`. The only way that I was able to get this working is to add `&& this.props.location.pathname !== '/profile'` to the `state.toProfile` condition. This feels a bit dirty. It seems like there is a better way.

I am taking the approach recommended in this blog post https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/, it seems like this doesn't work if the route you redirect to contains the same component as the route that was redirected from.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route component={Main} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

class Main extends Component {

    state = {
        toProfile: false
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.toProfile === true) {
            return <Redirect to='/profile' />
        }

        return (
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a route for `/profile`, atm profile goes to Main that goes to /profile... again

Comment: are you sending /profile to Main? or to another class?

Comment: I am sending it to Main and I get the same error. If I send it to Dashboard it works but obviously that's not what I want

Comment: if you send it to Main... Main is already mounted and will redirect again to /profile. you need to send to another component, or change the way you change the state so it doesn't redirect again

Comment: yeah, i guess I need another wrapper component /Profile that shares a lot in common with /Main hmm. Not sure what you mean in your second point about changing the way I change state.

Comment: you are setting `toProfile` to true somewhere... change it so it is back false, IMO  an ugly way... or redirect in another way...

Comment: yeah I tried to set it back to false but there is no good way to do that either. I think a new Profile component is the way to go. It might make sense to make sense for some code splitting down the line. hmm